# Two circle-stealth segments with same starting point, showing off-set

Tags: tikz-pgf, tkz-euclide

I want to draw two force. Therefor I'm using the definition of two segments with ikz-euclid. But when you look closely, the two circles are not starting on the same point. It seems like the circle of the starting point is rotating around the point A.
[image]

I can understand that is the correct way for the arrows.

My code is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, decorations.pathmorphing, calc,intersections,through,backgrounds,patterns,fit,arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzInit[ymax=3,xmax=8]
\tkzDefPoints{1/1/A};
\tkzDefShiftPoint[A](12:6){B};
\tkzDefShiftPoint[A](12:1.2){C};
\tkzDefShiftPoint[A](50:5){D};
%\tkzClip
\tkzGrid
\draw[red,Circle-stealth] (A) -- (B);
\draw[Circle-stealth] (A) -- (D);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I could change it to

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, decorations.pathmorphing, calc,intersections,through,backgrounds,patterns,fit,arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzInit[ymax=3,xmax=8]
\tkzDefPoints{1/1/A};
\tkzDefShiftPoint[A](12:6){B};
\tkzDefShiftPoint[A](12:1.2){C};
\tkzDefShiftPoint[A](50:5){D};
%\tkzClip
\tkzGrid
\draw[red,-stealth] (A) -- (B);
\draw[-stealth] (A) -- (D);
\tkzDrawPoint[fill=black](A)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Resulting in 
[image]

Which gives me the result that I want, but maybe there's a more elegant way of doing it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your method is just fine. The "bad" result is of course a result of the arrow tip being placed by its end point, not its center, i.e. the tip of the "arrow" is placed at the start/end of the path.

You could of course extend the line by the radius of the circular arrow tip, i.e. `\draw[red,{Circle[length=4pt]}-stealth,shorten <=-2pt] (A) -- (B);`, but adding the dot separately seems like less work.

Another option altogether is to define `A` as a `node` instead of a point, but use whichever you find most convenient.

```
\documentclass[border=4mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzInit[ymax=3,xmax=8]
\tkzGrid
\node [minimum size=3pt,inner sep=0pt,fill,circle,outer sep=0pt] (A) at (1,1) {};
\tkzDefShiftPoint[A](12:6){B};
\tkzDefShiftPoint[A](12:1.2){C};
\tkzDefShiftPoint[A](50:5){D};
%\tkzClip
\draw[red,-stealth] (A) -- (B);
\draw[-stealth] (A) -- (D);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

(Sidenote: You don't have to explicitly load `pgf` and `tikz` when you're loading `tkz-euclide` and/or `pgfplots` as well.)

Comment: @ Torbjørn I always keep my same MWE for asking questions, cleaning up most of it. I thought from the moment you draw something you need those packages. :-) (and for some reason the @ option not always work)

Comment: @Arne `tkz-euclide` loads `tikz`, as does `pgfplots`. `tikz` loads `pgf`.  As such, you only end up loading packages more than once. It might not hurt, but it's not needed.

Comment: @Arne You're always notified of comments to your own post, so `@` isn't necessary in those cases.